# Disable STS (Eclipse) 'Method stub' suggestion

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

The question is about Eclipse configuration (in fact I use STS but it's pretty much the same). Every time when I'm declaring some field in class Eclipse suggests me `Method stub` as the first position and only then the needed class, e.g. if I want to create EntityManager field it first suggests `Enti():void - method stub` and only then EntityManager which I need:
[image]
I never use this method stub (leaving alone that it doesn't make much sense to suggest method names started from the capital letter) so I'd really like to disable it but I've played a lot with different types of settings and still can't find it. 
Does anybody know whether it is possible at all? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the following preferences? Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but yes, I've been there and couldn't find anything that would disable this annoying stuff